# How to get three quarters of the fill_parent

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I already know that if you have n elements with equal heights=fill_parent, they get the same size so they fill the parent among all of them.

But I would like to have, for example a component 1/4 of the screen height, and another component 3/4. How can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [linear layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html) to do this

Use layout_weight to manipulate the ratio of fill.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/component1" android:text="hello"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.25" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/component2" android:text="world"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.75" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can also have the values as 1.0 and 3.0 respectively, just so long as the ratio is correct.

Comment: what tells you this? eclipse?  I didn't set the height of the textboxes in the example.  I have answered this question many times today. This is how you do it, I have tested this code also

Comment: Yes, I'm using Eclipse. Why is it marking it as a mistake then? Is it realted to any parameter I may have not written?

Comment: Yes, I am using 2.1. And no, this doesn't solve my problem. Floats are not allowed for layout_weight, and if I put 1 and 3 it asks me for units.

Comment: layout_weight IS a float value http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight

Comment: here is more google documentation http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html

Comment: layout_weight (XML) != public float weight (JAVA). So no, it is not a float. Anyway, it is Eclipse who is giving the error, not me. How can LinearLayout help me getting percentual areas?

Comment: layout_weight (XML) is a string which is parsed into float weight (JAVA).  You have asked for help and I have provided an answer which is known to work and reinforced with documentation by Google thenselves.  I have also retested the example given in 2.0,2.1,2.2 on Eclipse Indigo with the latest versions API's and ADT plugins.  I have recreated the project with different API levels and it works.  Linear layout obeys weight values of hild controls.  Other containers may not do so.  I cannot help you fursther as I cannot reproduce you problem.  Please try the simple example I have provided.